# python3, ftplib storlines error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

I want to upload an ASCII file. This used to work in Python 2:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.domain.com')
ftp.login('domain.com',password)
ftp.cwd('subdirectory')
ftp.storlines('STOR ' + 'file.htm', open('file.htm','r'))
ftp.close()
```

However, in Python 3 it returns this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/ftplib.py", line 497, in storlines
    if buf[-1] in B_CRLF: buf = buf[:-1]
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read the documentation:
http://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storlines

"Lines are read until EOF from the file object file (opened in binary mode) using its readline() method to provide the data to be stored."

So I just had to open in binary mode:

```
ftp.storlines('STOR ' + 'file.htm', open('file.htm','rb'))
```

Comment: I believe when tommy answered his own question, he left off a/the critical character ftp.storlines('STOR ' + 'file.htm', open('file.htm','rb')) unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Thanks Raleigh! Fixed.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, but my error was `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` Maybe a newer version?

Comment: @HansGoldman using Python 3.6? I get your error on 3.6, but the other exception 'Type str doesn't support the buffer API' occurs on python 3.4 and lower..

Comment: @JackO'neill I am using Python 3.5.2

Comment: @HansGoldman I get the same error as you, and this solution worked for me. I have to read the file in binary mode. I can ftp it using either storlines or storbinary, but storbinary caused some corruption in the text file while storlines did not.